# Print certain number of rows of a multidimensional array at a time

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, increment

I have two arrays of dimension `x.shape=(1000000, 2000)` and `y.shape=(1000000, 200)`. I want to iterate through all of the columns and print the arrays with dimension `(800, 2000)`, `(1600, 2000)`, ... etc.,  increasing with 800 rows at a time. How would I go forth about this?

I've been trying the following:

```
counter = 0
increment = 800

for i in range(counter+increment):
    x[i, :]
    y[i, :]
    if len(x)==counter && len(x)<10000000:
        print(x, y)
        counter = counter + increment
```

But I'm not getting the result I want

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Specifically, why do you mention `y`?

Comment: `x[i,:]` by itself on a line doesn't do anything.  It doesn't change `x`.  Have you experimented with small arrays in an interactive session?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if I understand what you want to achieve, but maybe this does help? Range has a step size, that might do the trick you are looking for. Also, you need to slice the arrays from 0 to your counter.

```
for i in range(0, x.shape[0], 8000):
    print(x[:i, :], y[:i, :])
```

Comment: You definitely need a start index in each of those slices

Comment: Why do you think so? In the question the slices grow by the increment. OP never asked to have continuing "frames". If he needs that, yes, starting indices are necessary, but he didn't say that. So if the question is improved my answer needs change as well.

Comment: Yeah, not the most detailed question, that's why I start saying that I'm unsure :-) But from what I understood might be asked I tried to give a hint.